# NetSuite Return Authorization transform from Sales Order which status is pending fulfillment

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I created a button via script tried to make sales return process automatically. In some situations, I need to create Return Authorization before items be fulfilled. However, NetSuite seems like not allow this action.

After clicked button, I got the error message below(the number is my sales order internal id):

`You can not initialize returnauthorization: invalid reference 21547.`

Here is my code:

```
 var RARec = record.transform({
                fromType: 'salesorder',
                fromId: SOId,
                toType: 'returnauthorization',
                isDynamic: true
            });

 for (k in returnItemKeys){
        let key = returnItemKeys[k];
        RARec.selectNewLine({ sublistId: "item" });
        RARec.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: "item", fieldId: "item", value: key });
        RARec.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: "item", fieldId: "quantity", value: returnItemObj[key].quantity });
        RARec.setCurrentSublistValue({ sublistId: "item", fieldId: "amount", value: 0 });
 }
var RAId = RARec.save();
```

After the error happened, I tried another way. This way could create Return Authorization, But it didn' t linked the Sales Order, the code like below:

```
var RARec = record.create({
                type: 'returnauthorization',
                isDynamic: true,
                defaultValues: {
                    entity: eCustomer,
                }
            });
RARec.setValue({fieldId:'createdfrom', value:SOId}); //it doesn't workds
```

Is there any way to create Return Authorization which linked Sales Order before Sales Order Items be fullfilled(stauspending fulfillment)?

Comment: If Im not wrong, you can´t transform saleOrder to ReturnAutorization, just Invoice to ReturnAutorization ,   var ReAuth = record.transform({
              fromType: record.Type.INVOICE,
              fromId: context.createdfrom.id,
              toType: record.Type.RETURN_AUTHORIZATION,
              isDynamic: true

Comment: @wozzarvl
Sales Order can transform to Return Authorization, but it must work at least one item be fulfilled. So, I fulfill this Sales Order and transform a Return Authorization. After that, I delete the Item Fulfillment, that is my solution now. But it' s not a good solution.